# MaxScript defining variables in struct

Tags: 3dsmax, maxscript

How would I define a variable in a struct?

So for example:

```
struct test (
     variable = 123
)
```

If I were to do this:

```
 test.variable
```

It would not find it. How would I make it so I can access the value of the variable in the struct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just figured it out:

```
v = test()
v.variable
```

That should work.